# Watir Rspec Ruby : Comparing new/edited value with old/previous value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, watir, rspec-rails

Auto generated name twice, first

```
 $name = generate_name 
    self.name = $name
```

produces: `$name is "Abc"`

And then edited the `$name` to be "Xyz".  Which causes the previous/old name to be no longer available/saved in the app, its overwritten by new/edited name.

I now have to compare the two values of same variable $name to ensure that name is edited.

```
using expect($name).to_not  eq($old_name)
```

I don't understand how to save the previous/old name into another variable `$old_name` before overwriting it?

Comment: Why on earth are you using globals? (starting a variable name with $ makes it a global in ruby).  Use [`let` instead](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-2/docs/helper-methods/let-and-let). Globals are evil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you change `$name` to be "Xyz", or test for equality, you need to set `$old_name` to be equal to `$name`.

Something like this:

```
$name = generate_name
self.name = $name
$old_name = self.name

$name = Xyz
self.name = $name

using expect($name).to_not eq($old_name)
```

Comment: actually the same generate name method is executed twice to create and then edit name, so if $old_name =self.name is executed again during edit it will overwrite its value too I have too I have to run the same method twice but have assign $old_name only for once.

Comment: its like def create_name  $name = generate_name
self.name = $name
$old_name = self.name

$name = generate_name
self.name = $name end ......have to assign value to $old_name out side the generate_name method i.e. globally